# Populate a reportviewer by codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

Im using reportviewer with `strongly dataset` but now
 I need to populate my reportviewer via codebehind. But I'm getting this error:
`A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'ds_blabla'.`
Here's my code to feed the dataset:

```
public DataSet PreencheDS(Relatorios rel)
  {
     DataSet retorno = new DataSet();
     try
       {
         string sql = @"SELECT proj.descricao AS projeto, func.descricao AS funcionalidade, clb.clube AS cliente, ch.descricao
         FROM MyTable ch 
         INNER JOIN table1 proj ON MyTable.projeto = table1.id 
         INNER JOIN table2 func ON MyTable.funcionalidade = table2.id 
         INNER JOIN table3 clb ON MyTable.clube = table3 .id
         WHERE (MyTable.responsavel = @responsavel) AND (MyTable.clube = @clube) AND (MyTable.dt_cadastro >= @dt_inicial) AND (MyTable.dt_cadastro <= @dt_final)";                
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@responsavel", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = rel.Responsavel_ID;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@clube", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = rel.Clube_ID;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_inicial", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = rel.Dt_Inicial;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_final", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = rel.Dt_Final;
                retorno = _dal.Consultar(cmd);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            return retorno;
        }
```

And here's the page that contains my `ReportViewer`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if (!IsPostBack)
           {
              rel.Responsavel_ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["usrValue"].ToString());
              rel.Clube_ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clube_id"].ToString());
              rel.Dt_Inicial = Session["dt_inicial"].ToString() + " 00:00:00";
              rel.Dt_Final = Session["dt_final"].ToString() + " 23:59:59";

              DataSet ds = _rel.PreencheDS(rel);
              ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("MyTable", ds.Tables[0]);              
              this.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
              this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
              this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
              this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

I want to do it by `codebehind` instead of using `strongly dataset` because I need to pass `parameters` to my reportviewer. But these `parameters` they may vary... So I want to do it by `codebehind`.

**UPDATE**
I did like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15971652/1919644). Now there's no message anymore, but nothing appears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line, instead of `MyTable`, it should read `ds_blabla`:

```
ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("MyTable", ds.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the error message does not appear anymore \o/ yeey. But nothing appears at all. And I tested my query on my sql manager, it return emptySet... Could you tell me what's wrong on my query ?

Comment: No, because I don't have access to your database. You will have to work that out yourself ;-)

Comment: OK, now the error is gone, but nothing appears... The Dataset is not empty, maybe there is something else  wrong ?