# Populate Report Viewer From Code using SQLCommand in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer, rdlc

I would like to be able to populate a report viewer with a SQLCommand **with out using** a stored procedure. I have crated a report rdlc and setup it up with the columns from my table.

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2013
- .Net Framework 4.5
- Report Viewer 11
- ASP.NET Project

Here is my code:

```
 var Class_Connection = new SQL_Connection();
                Class_Connection.cnn.Close();
                Class_Connection.cnn.Open();

var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TT", Class_Connection.cnn);
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
var source = new ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt);
RV_Main.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CCD/TT/Report/MyReport.rdlc");
RV_Main.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
RV_Main.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

I have see other post like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971400/populate-a-reportviewer-by-codebehind). But that is using a stored procedure. I would like to do this with a select statement in a few lines as possible. Can someone please give me an example on how to do this?

Comment: if the examples that you are seeing are using a stored procedure then you should without any problems do the same thing passing / using dynamic sql text.. what have you actually tried on your own.. this is actually quite simple in nature believe it or not..but you will need to show a little bit more effort on your part respectfully speaking @nate

Comment: @MethodMan I am sorry about that, I thought I added my code. I corrected my post.

Comment: Sanatize your input though! Remember [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Data Source in the Report Viewer GUI. Then reference that Data Set you used in the Data Source in the code like so:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TT", Class_Connection.cnn);
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
var source = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
RV_Main.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CCD/TT/Report/MyReport.rdlc");
RV_Main.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
RV_Main.LocalReport.Refresh();
```